# Expect script failing to continue

Tags: expect

I have an expect script which is logging onto a device and sending a command, however the script completes without finishing, its like the last expect isn't being picked up.

How do I enable debugging to watch the script progress so I can identify where the issues is?

My script looks like this...

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set hostname [lindex $argv 0]
set username "a.user"
set password "a.pass"
spawn telnet $hostname
expect "Username:" {
  send "$username\r"
  expect "Password:"
  send "$password\r"
}
expect "#" {
    send "sh ver\r"
}
```

It stops processing at the below line;

```
expect "#" {
```

however I can clearly see the # in the last output.

Thanks

Comment: run you script with `expect -d` -- the verbose debugging output will give you the reason.

Comment: @Grev : Can you try adding one more `expect` after the last `send` command ?